# Assign pandas row as dictionary key with other row being the value (to represent pairs)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-structures

I am working on a data processing task in Python using Pandas, where I need to pair rows from a DataFrame based on specific criteria and then store these pairs for further processing. My challenge is to efficiently store these pairs in a dictionary, with each pair comprising two DataFrame rows (an 'a' entry and a 'b' entry).
EDIT: Every 'a' entry is paired to **one** 'b' entry. Elements where no pair was foudn are not added to the dictionary.

Context:

- Each row in my DataFrame represents an event with a 'Seat' identifier and a 'Note' (either 'a' or 'b')
- I need to pair each 'a' entry with a subsequent 'b' entry for the same 'Seat'.
- The DataFrame is sorted by 'Seat' and time, ensuring 'a' entries appear before their corresponding 'b' entries.

Problem:

I want to use a dictionary to store these pairs for efficient retrieval and manipulation later. The ideal structure would be:

`{ a_entry : b_entry }`

However its not possible to do this, since rows are unhashable.

I prefer having it as a dictionary because that way I can merge these two rows very easily like this in a loop:

```
    merged_entries = {}

    for a_entry, b_entry in pairs_dict.items():
        code = '19' if a_entry['Asleep'] and b_entry['Asleep'] else '11'
        if code == '19':
            logging.info(f"Changed code from 11 to 19 for seat {a_entry['Seat']}")
        
        merged_entry = {
            'Seat': a_entry['Seat'],
            'Starttime': a_entry['Starttime'],
            'Endtime': b_entry['Endtime'],
            'Duration': b_entry['Endtime'] - a_entry['Starttime'],
            'Code': code,
            'Notes': None,
            'Asleep': a_entry['Asleep'],
            'Concert': a_entry['Concert'],
            'Camera_Position': a_entry['Camera_Position'],
            'Composer': a_entry['Composer'],
            'Movement': a_entry['Movement'],
            'File_Name': a_entry['File_Name']
        }
        merged_entries.append(merged_entry)
```

```
# Here's sample data
data = {
    'Seat': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'Starttime': [datetime(2023, 1, 1, 9, 0),
                  datetime(2023, 1, 1, 9, 30),
                  datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 0),
                  datetime(2023, 1, 1, 9, 15),
                  datetime(2023, 1, 1, 9, 45),
                  datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 10),
                  datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 30),
                  datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 50),
                  datetime(2023, 1, 1, 11, 10)],
    'Endtime': [datetime(2023, 1, 1, 9, 20),
                datetime(2023, 1, 1, 9, 50),
                datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 20),
                datetime(2023, 1, 1, 9, 35),
                datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 5),
                datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 20),
                datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 50),
                datetime(2023, 1, 1, 11, 0),
                datetime(2023, 1, 1, 11, 20)],
    'Type': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
    'Asleep': [False, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, False],
    'Code': [11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11],
    'Notes': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    'Concert': ['Concert1', 'Concert1', 'Concert1', 'Concert2', 'Concert2', 'Concert3', 'Concert3', 'Concert3', 'Concert3'],
    'Camera_Position': ['Front', 'Front', 'Front', 'Back', 'Back', 'Left', 'Left', 'Left', 'Left'],
    'Composer': ['Bach', 'Bach', 'Bach', 'Mozart', 'Mozart', 'Beethoven', 'Beethoven', 'Beethoven', 'Beethoven'],
    'Movement': ['Adagio', 'Adagio', 'Adagio', 'Allegro', 'Allegro', 'Fur Elise', 'Fur Elise', 'Fur Elise', 'Fur Elise'],
    'File_Name': ['file1.csv', 'file1.csv', 'file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv', 'file3.csv', 'file3.csv', 'file3.csv']
}
```

I tried:

1. Converting rows to tuples or strings, but this approach loses the ability to manipulate the data as a DataFrame
2. Using other data structures like lists, but I prefer a dictionary for its O(1) retrieval time.

Comment: It seems that one 'a' entry can also have two 'b' entries or none at all?

Comment: every 'a' entry is unique and only paired with a 'b' entry, if the 'a' entry was the last that came before the 'b' entry. 

So if we have 'a', 'a', 'b', then only the second 'a' is paired with the 'b' and the first 'a' not added to our dictionary.

Comment: One thing you can do is to store the row index or the row position of the 'a' row as key instead of the row itself and at the beginning of the for-loop you can retrieve the actual row with `loc` or `iloc`.

Comment: *"`{ a_entry : b_entry }` However its not possible to do this, since rows are unhashable."* << It's totally possible, if `a_entry` and `b_entry` are row numbers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, rows cannot be dict keys, because pandas series are not hashable. To process the data the way need it, you can instead iterate over the rows and keep track of the rows that meet your conditions:

```py
def merge_entries(df, a_i, b_i):
    a_entry = df.iloc[a_i]
    b_entry = df.iloc[a_i]

    code = '19' if a_entry['Asleep'] and b_entry['Asleep'] else '11'
    if code == '19':
        logging.info(f"Changed code from 11 to 19 for seat {a_entry['Seat']}")
    
    merged_entry = {
        'Seat': a_entry['Seat'],
        'Starttime': a_entry['Starttime'],
        'Endtime': b_entry['Endtime'],
        'Duration': b_entry['Endtime'] - a_entry['Starttime'],
        'Code': code,
        'Notes': None,
        'Asleep': a_entry['Asleep'],
        'Concert': a_entry['Concert'],
        'Camera_Position': a_entry['Camera_Position'],
        'Composer': a_entry['Composer'],
        'Movement': a_entry['Movement'],
        'File_Name': a_entry['File_Name']
    }
    
    return merged_entry


def process_entries(df):
    t = df.iterrows()

    a_i = None
    b_i = None

    merged_entries = []

    for i, row in t:
        if (a_i is None and row.Type == 'a'):
            a_i = i
            continue
        if (a_i is None and row.Type != 'a'):
            a_i = None
        if (b_i is None and row.Type == 'b'):
            b_i = i

        if a_i is not None and b_i is not None:
            merged_entries.append(merge_entries(df, a_i, b_i))
            a_i = None
            b_i = None

    return merged_entries


process_entries(df)
```

This will give you the result:

```
[{'Seat': 1,
  'Starttime': Timestamp('2023-01-01 09:00:00'),
  'Endtime': Timestamp('2023-01-01 09:50:00'),
  'Duration': Timedelta('0 days 00:50:00'),
  'Code': '11',
  'Notes': None,
  'Asleep': False,
  'Concert': 'Concert1',
  'Camera_Position': 'Front',
  'Composer': 'Bach',
  'Movement': 'Adagio',
  'File_Name': 'file1.csv'},
 {'Seat': 2,
  'Starttime': Timestamp('2023-01-01 09:15:00'),
  'Endtime': Timestamp('2023-01-01 10:05:00'),
  'Duration': Timedelta('0 days 00:50:00'),
  'Code': '19',
  'Notes': None,
  'Asleep': True,
  'Concert': 'Concert2',
  'Camera_Position': 'Back',
  'Composer': 'Mozart',
  'Movement': 'Allegro',
  'File_Name': 'file2.csv'},
 {'Seat': 3,
  'Starttime': Timestamp('2023-01-01 10:10:00'),
  'Endtime': Timestamp('2023-01-01 11:00:00'),
  'Duration': Timedelta('0 days 00:50:00'),
  'Code': '11',
  'Notes': None,
  'Asleep': False,
  'Concert': 'Concert3',
  'Camera_Position': 'Left',
  'Composer': 'Beethoven',
  'Movement': 'Fur Elise',
  'File_Name': 'file3.csv'}]
```